# How to check which TLS cipher suite is used in tcp connection

Tags: networking, wireshark, tls

I am using [imapfilter](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter) to sort my mails on a remote IMAP server provided by some company. My configuration restricts [imapfilter](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter) to the usage of TLS 1.2 via STARTTLS. I do know how to check which TLS cipher suites are supported by the IMAP server via [sslyze](https://github.com/iSECPartners/sslyze). I would like to know how to verify that TLS 1.2 is indeed used and which cipher suite is chosen. Is there e.g. some wireshark incantation which answers this question easily? Or is there some other tools that can be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use OpenSSL's `s_client` command-line tool for this, *e.g.*:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 1.2.3.4:143 -starttls imap ...
```

The key part is the `-starttls imap` option; without this, `s_client` will try to perform the SSL/TLS handshake immediately after connecting.

The rest of the `s_client` output should show you the negotiated ciphersuite, protocol version, and other useful information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not observe which cypher is actually used when imapfilter connects. But it shows what cypher could be chosen.

Comment: If you know the TLS-related `imapfilter` configuration (_e.g._ its ciphersuites/protocol versions), you should be able to set them via the `openssl s_client` command-line options to show (ideally) what _is_ used when `imapfilter` connects, yes?